# Publish Blog Post command line

Tags: 7, nodes

I've been looking around the Internet trying to investigate how to publish a blog post via either rest APIs or other command line tools. However, I have not found a way to do this. How can I publish a blog post (or node) either through a command line, rest APIs, or another way programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 6 has a module to publish to a site via external GUI applications. It supports different XML-RPC based blogging APIs, such as the [Blogger API](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/1_docs/), the [new Blogger Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/blogger/), the [MetaWeblog API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi), and most of the [Movable Type API](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/blogger_api/).

In Drupal 7, the module has been removed from core, and it is now a [third-party module](https://www.drupal.org/project/blogapi).

#### Reference

- [BlogAPI: post from blog tools](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/blogapi)